# Git - How to commit an n+2 modification before a (non saved) n+1 modification

Tags: git

Beyond the messy title (using Git) how can I modify and commit a file that is already added in staging area but with the ability to keeping the original staged one in order to commit it after?

Maybe it still not enough clear so here a simple example to illustrate:

1. I make a `test.txt` file with the following specified content `ABC` (say file v1)
2. I commit it, customer is happy..
3. Then I'm asked to made the following modification `ABC DEF` (say file v2)
4. I make the modification but I do not staged or commited it
5. And on my own initiative I changed the file to `ABC DEF GHI` (say file v3)
6. Now I'm happy with this file but I realized that I did not staged or commited the previous one (the v2), but I want also to keep this v3 for later.

So at this stage:

1. How can I save my v3 modifications within Git?
2. Then going back to file v2 by undoing my modifications then commiting v2..
3. Restoring my v3?
4. Commiting my v3?

I tried the following after the step 6 above:

7. I did on v3 `git add .` => `git status` show **changes to be commited** in green
8. I modified the file and come back to my v2 => `git status` show me **changes to be commited** in green AND ALSO (as expected) **changes not staged for commits** in red
9. I tried a `git commit -am "v2"` but I lost all my v3 work since `git status` showed me **nothing to commit**

I hope that this trivial explanation is clear enough without being boring. But in reality here is my more realistic situation:

1. I had a feature A to implement on a file.
2. I made the required changes in the file and added the feature A.
3. But without realising I added a custom feature B in order to try something.
4. I then realized that this new feature B was good enough to keep it for later.

This time I managed this awkward workflow with good old filesystem management (aka renaming the file) but this bad habit is not going to leave me soon enough so at least I wanted to do this weird process with Git.

Thank you again

Comment: Do your commits and reorder them with `git rebase -i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you made some changes to a set of files. Now you want to divide those changes into 2 commits (v2 and v3) based on the feature they correspond to. Try staging the changes using

#### git add -p

This is the shorthand of git add --patch and lets you interactively choose between the hunks of changes. Let's say you want to commit v2 first. Enter 'y' for the changes corresponding to v2 and 'n' for v3. If the hunk consists of both v2 and v3 changes, then split it by entering 's'.
After committing for v2, go on to stage v3 changes and make the commit.

If you don't want to stage or commit the changes for v3 yet, but you want git to save it for later, then "stashing" the changes is the best option you have.
Simply,

#### git stash

to stash all the unstaged changes.

If you want to cherry-pick the changes to stash you can do:

#### git stash -p

I like giving my stashes names so that I can remember later what the changes are about. For that do:

#### git stash save -p Name_here

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you.. I did not even heard about the `stash` commande or the `--patch` option when I follow some Git tutorials.. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Two minor goofs.

[`-a` is the "all" switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_options). When you use it, git takes the worktree version of everything in the index. You wanted v2 in the index and `git commit-m v2`.

Without `-a` `git commit` commits only what's in the index, so get your v2 content indexed and commit that.

I agree with c-rish, `git add --patch` is your tool here, selectively add changes from the worktree.  With v3 in the worktree, git add --patch and select just the v2 changes. There's also a `git reset --patch` to selectively undo changes too.

Comment: I thought that option `-a` when using with `commit` mean **add**.  So to commit changes without staging it.